# Creating a table with an initial element selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cellrenderer

I want to create a table which displays in each row a set of data, in addition to a radio button for possible selection. 
This can be achieved easily by using a simple table model class which extends the DefaultTableModel and a cell renderer and editor class which implements the TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor interfaces respectively. 
What I really couldn't manage to do is to make the table to display initially one of the elements (rows) initially selected. It seems straightforward but it isn't...does anybody have a clue about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your exact requirement.

```
table.changeSelection(2, 0, false, false);
```

will select the row and make the cell have focus in the table

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`setSelectionInterval()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionInterval(int,%20int%29) method of the table's [`ListSelectionModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html):

```
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(4, 5);
```